# Get Attribute on Models not to global data . Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a data on users model like tanggal_lahir or in english its like **dob** , i create this on User Models to change this format date . like this :

```
  public function getTanggalLahirAttribute()
  {
     return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($this->attributes['tanggal_lahir'])

    ->format('d, F-Y ');
  }
```

i know its changed global value form tanggal_lahir to format **d,F-Y** , but now i have a problem , on specific form (update data form) i need a normall value not d,F-Y in this script

```
 <input id="tanggal_lahir" type="date" class="form-control @error('tanggal_lahir') is-invalid 
  @enderror" name="tanggal_lahir" value="{{$pns->users->tanggal_lahir}}" 
  required autocomplete="tanggal_lahir">
```

its form input on update form , if i active  **getTanggalLahirAttribute()** , this value on form not showing , but if i delete/non active this **getTanggalLahirAttribute()** its will back to normall value (showing)

so in my question how i can specified using

```
\Carbon\Carbon::parse($this->attributes['tanggal_lahir'])

    ->format('d, F-Y ')
```

on my view . i using datatables yajra ,

Answer (score 0):

**Getter** allow you to modify data that you retrieve from database. If you want to use getter. Follow this sameple of code.

```
public function getTanggalLahirAttribute($value) {
  $date = Carbon::create($value);
        $date->setToStringFormat('d, F-Y');

        return $date;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: so , how i can use this on view ?  {{ $date }} , like this ?

Comment: @AdhikMulat Please do not using any logic of code in blade files. It should response data from controller. It's bad practice.

Comment: now in my blade on tanggal_lahir is = [object Object]

Comment: @AdhikMulat But, if you still want to use it into your blade.

Comment: using this line of code. \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d, F-Y', {{$pns->users->tanggal_lahir}}) into your input. But, I am not recommended.

Comment: no , i solved this with $pns->users->getOriginal('tanggal_lahir') just like this , many thank you sir